# Solving Using Integrating Factors Found By Inspection

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

Can the Differential Equation below be solve using Integrating Factors Found By Inspection? If yes, how?
$$2x^5y'=y(3x^4+y^2)$$

Comment: It is a Bernoulli equation, that should give you a start.

Comment: Strictly, then you setting the usual substitution for the Bernoulli equation $2x^{5}y'-3x^{4}y=y^{3}$, you has a linear equation can be solven by the usual integration factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2x^{5}y'=y(3x^{4}+y^{2})$

$(3yx^{4}+y^{3})dx+(-2x^{5})dy=0$

$Integrating factor :μ(x,y)=x^{m} y^{n}$  , We multiply in the equation

$(3 y^{n+1} x^{m+4}+x^{m}y^{n+3})dx+(-2x^{m+5}y^{n})dy=0$

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=3(n+1) y^{n}x^{m+4}+(n+3)y^{n+2}x^{m}$

$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-2(m+5)x^{m+4}y^{n}$

The condition of exact of the differential equation : $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

$n+3=0 , 3(n+1)=-2(m+5) $

$n=-3 , m=-2 $

then : Integrating factor :$μ(x,y)=x^{-2} y^{-3}$

$(3y^{-2}x^{2}+x^{-2})dx+(-2x^{3}y^{-3})dy=0$

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-6y^{-3}x^{2}$

$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=M(x,y)$

$f(x,y)=\int (3y^{-2}x^{2}+x^{-2})dx+h(y)$

$f(x,y)=x^{3}y^{-2}-x^{-1}+h(y)$

$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=N(x,y)$

$-2x^{3}y^{-3}+h'(y)=-2x^{3}y^{-3}$

$h'(y)=0 $

$h(y)=$c<sub>1</sub>

$f(x,y)=x^{3}y^{-2}-x^{-1}=C$

note : Of course, this is also Bernoulli's differential equation. Another method can be converted to homogenization. Another method can be converted to separable

Answer (score 0):

another way : by Homogenization

let ; $y=t^{a} , dy=a t^{a-1} dt$

$(3t{a}x^{4}+t^{3a})dx+(-2at^{a-1}x^{5})dt=0$

to homogenize : $a+4=3a=a-1+5$ , $a=2$

$(3t^{2}x^{4}+t^{6})dx+(-4tx^{5})dt=0$

$t((3tx^{4}+t^{5})dx+(-4x^{5})dt))=0$

$t=0 , t^{2}=y , y=0 $

$(3tx^{4}+t^{5})dx+(-4x^{5})dt=0$

$\frac{dt}{dx}={\frac{3t}{4x}}+{\frac{t^{5}}{4x^{5}}}$

substitute : $z={\frac{t}{x}}$

$t'=z'x+z$

$z'x+z={\frac{3}{4}}z+{\frac{z^{5}}{4}}$

$4z'x=-z+z^{5}$

${\int(z^{5}-z)^{-1}dz}={\int (4x)^{-1}dx}$

$ln(-z^{4}+1)-4ln(z)=ln(x)+ln(c)$

$ln(z^{-4}-1)=ln(cx)$

$z^{-4}-1=cx$

$z={\frac{t}{x}}$ , $t^{2}=y$

${x^{4}}{y^{-2}}-1=cx$

$x^{3}y^{-2}-x^{-1}=C$

Answer (score 0):

OK OK another way!

substitute : $y=(zx)^{2}$

$y'=2xz^{2}+2zz'x^{2}$

$2x^{5}(2xz^{2}+2zz'x^{2})=(zx)^{2}(3x^{4}+(zx)^{4})$

$z(2(2z+2z'x)-z(3+z^{4}))=0$

$z=0$,$y=(zx)^{2}$,$y=0$

$2(2z+2z'x)-z(3+z^{4})=0$

$4z'x=z^{5}-z$

$4{\int (z^{5}-z)^{-1}dz}={\int x^{-1} dx}$

$ln(-z^{4}+1)-4ln(z)=ln(x)+ln(c)$

$z^{-4}-1=cx$

$y=(zx)^{2}$

$x^{4}y^{-2}-1=cx$

$x^{3}y^{-2}-x^{-1}=C$